# Change Android Circle Button Press in CodenameOne

Tags: android, codenameone

I have noticed that when a button is pressed with Android (simulating with a galaxy S5) a circle is created from the origin of the button press and stretches to fill the entire  button if held long enough. Is there any way to override this functionality, so that pressing the button would not have this circle?

[Example of large button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMYAS.png)

Comment: The effect is called ripple. If you set the `android:background`, the effect disappears, unless you set it to a drawable which defines a ripple.

Comment: This question is explicity referred to Codename One.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **Codename One Developer Guide** [section 5.8.3 "Ripple effect"](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html#_ripple_effect):

> The ripple effect in material design highlights the location of the
>   finger and grows as a circle to occupy the full area of the component
>   as the user presses the button.
>
> We have the ability to perform a ripple effect by darkening the
>   touched area and growing that in a quick animation.
>
> Ripple effect can be applied to any component but we currently only
>   have it turned on for buttons on Android which also applies to things
>   like title commands, side menu elements etc. This might not apply at
>   this moment to lead components like multi-buttons but that might
>   change in the future.
>
> `Component` has a property to enable the ripple effect
>   `setRippleEffect(boolean)` and the corresponding `isRippleEffect()`. You
>   can turn it on or off individually in the component level. However,
>   `Button` has static `setButtonRippleEffectDefault(boolean)` and
>   `isButtonRippleEffectDefault()`. These allow us to define the default
>   behavior for all the buttons and that can be configured via the theme
>   constant `buttonRippleBool` which is currently on by default on the
>   native Android theme.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to disable ripple effect on button, try adding

> android:background

to the button with appropriate color.

Answer (score 0):

That is called the ripple effect and is the standard visual cue on Material Design for telling the user the button was interacted with.

To disable the ripple effect you can change the background color:

`android:background="@color/colorAccent"`

The previous is the most simple but the not recommended because that will make a flat not-interactive button. The user can't see when is pressed.

A better solution is to create a drawable like the following and that use it as a background:

> bg_btn.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <color android:color="@color/colorAccentDark"/>
    </item>

    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Then you can use it like this:

`android:background="@drawable/bg_btn"`